Combine routes from application.properties and env variables in spring cloud gateway
I have a set of routes in application.properties and a set of routes in env variables.
The problem is only env routes are loading but not the other routes from application.properties.
How to combine both of them programatically?

This is a limitation of spring boot and list properties. There's an open enhancement request to add a map of routes which can be merged across property sources, in your case env variables and application properties

Have you started working on it? :)

no we have not started on it
